# Is it possible to define a record with keys and values based on another record type but augment the key names?

Tags: typescript

If I have the following record type,

```js
type State = {
  currentPartnerId: number;
  currentTime: string;
};
```

I want to create a new type that has keys such as `getCurrentPartnerId` and properties that are functions which return the matching key in `State` type.

E.g.

```js
type NewType = {
  getCurrentParternerId: () => number;
  getCurrentTime: () => string;
}
```

I tried the following,

```js
type Dict<T extends keyof State> = { [key in `get${Capitalize<T>}`]: () => State[T] }
```

But that requires supplying a type argument which I don't want to do...

Answer (score 0):

You were very close.

```js
type Dict = { [key in keyof State as `get${Capitalize<key>}`]: () => State[key] }
```